# Obtain Data points from a graph on an image without axes

Tags: graphics

I have the following image:
(which is a oscillation of the "magnetic susceptibility of gold"  in y-direction, in arbitrary units, 
over the "magnetic field strength" from bmin = 36540 Gauss to bmax = 36784 Gauss, in x-direction).

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6JOc.png"]
```

[image: plot image]

Even if it looks periodic, it should not be so, it must be periodic in 1/x (i.e. in the reciprocal of the field strength). 
Changing the image to a plot over 1/x I already succeeded in with the following *Mathematica* function:

```
bmin := 36540;

bmax := 36784;

f[a_, b_] := {1/(1/bmin - 1/bmax) (1/(a*(bmax - bmin) + bmin) - 1/bmax), b} 

img = ImageTransformation[pic, f[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Now I get an image which looks quite similar and goes from 1/bmax to 1/bmin in the x-direction.
From that image I now want to obtain the data points (along x) in y direction, such that I can do a Fourier Transform to obtain the frequencies and hence the periods in the reciprocal field strength.

How would I do that the easiest way?

btw: The background is that my professor wants us to obtain those frequencies in a problem set on the De-Haas-Van-Alphen-effct but obviously "by hand" with ruler and pen on a printed version of the graph...and I´m not gonna do that :)

Answer (score 9):

Transform your image into a grayscale version, no alpha channel, and negate the color:

```
img = RemoveAlphaChannel[ColorNegate@ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]]
```

Then, extract the array of pixel values:

```
data = ImageData[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]];
Dimensions@data
  (* return {156, 726} *)
```

In that array, white is 1 and black is 0. Then, simply calculate for each row the weighted average:

```
Total[Table[i*#[[i]], {i, Length@#}]]/Total@# & /@ Transpose[data];
```

(I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do that, without a table…) Then plot the result:

```
ListLinePlot[Flatten@%]
```

[image]

*Voilà!*

PS: I'd advise you to perform that on the original, scanned image instead, and only transform the coordinates afterward. (Also note: in that very narrow region of abscissa, the inversion $x \rightarrow 1/x$ is probably close enough to linear that you can neglect it…

---

**Edit —** okay, one mistake: the data as obtained by the above method has an inverted $y$ axis. You can fix it with:

```
t = Flatten[Total[Table[i*#[[i]], {i, Length@#}]]/Total@# & /@ Transpose[data]];
ListLinePlot[Dimensions[data][[1]] - # & /@ t]
```

Plotting the obtained data on top of the original picture reveals that it works well:

```
Show[
 pic,
 ListLinePlot[Dimensions[data][[1]] - # & /@ t, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]
```

[image]

However, you can see that some of the amplitude of the original data is lost due to the averaging procedure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But unfortunately I don't understand much of it. In the array you've named "data" you have for each point in the x-y-plane a value between 0 and 1, with white correspondig to 1 and black to 0 and in between is what? And to which image belong those, to the inverted one or the original? And that explained what does the function `Total[Table[i*#[[i]], {i,Length@#}]]/Total@# & /@ Transpose[data];`
actually do (I do not understand the syntax - I'm not that strong with mathematica & image processing at all).

Comment: And finally the curvature of your plot does not agree with the one in the original and neither with the 1/x transformed original!? (This got cut off from tobi's "answer"...)