# Best fit equation from a scanned image

Tags: image-processing, fitting

I am trying to extract a curve from a scanned graph and find a best fit equation. For example, starting from:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How could one find an equation starting from the image file ?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-can-i-extract-data-points-from-a-black-and-white-image

Comment: Also [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1524/7167)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something to get you started, (assembled from [Andy Ross' code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1528/363)).  Data points are extracted from a data series in an image.

Your original image will need some editing in order to process each curve separately.

The following tadpoles plot is used for example.

```
img = Import@"http://www.biologycorner.com/resources/graph_tadpoles.JPG";
data = Round[ImageData[img], 1];
col = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Round[ImageData[img], 1], 1]];
Graphics[{RGBColor[#], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Tiny] & /@ col
```

Select which colour to extract, `col[[3]]`:

```
binImage = Image@Replace[data, {col[[3]] -> 1, _ :> 0}, {2}];
curve = ImageApply[{0, 0, 0} &, binImage, 
   Masking -> ColorNegate[Binarize[GaussianFilter[binImage, 5]]]];
curvLoc = (Reverse /@ Position[ImageData[curve, DataReversed -> True], {1., 1., 1.}]);
ListPlot[curvLoc, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Extract the top line.

```
groups = GatherBy[curvLoc, First];
maxes = Last@Sort@# & /@ groups;
ListLinePlot[Sort@maxes, ImageSize -> 500]
```

Note this actually is the top line.  You'll have to judge whether adjustment is needed.

```
Show[ListPlot[curvLoc, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Orange]],
 ListLinePlot[Sort@maxes], ImageSize -> 800]
```

From there you can analyse the data points.

To scale the data points it's helpful if the original image is clipped to know axis dimensions.  Then you can use `ImageDimensions` to scale the data.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you have two questions in one: (1) How to "take" the curve from the image into Mma? and (2) How to fit it?.

Here I address the first question and give one possible solution aditional to the ones offered before.

Some time ago I [published a function copyCurve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358) on this site, along with its detailed description. You can take it from there.

1. Copy the image from the screen (Right click, and choose "Copy image") and paste it inside the brackets of the function copyCurve

   copyCurve[place your image here]
2. Evaluate the resulting expression.
3. Follow the instructions for the program published on the site mentioned above and place the cursors along the curve of your choice. I have chosen the blue one for the sake of example. You should obtain something like this:
   [image]
4. As soon as this is done, press the button "Make the list of the curve points" and then in a separate cell evaluate the variable listOfPoints. You will get the following list for the blue line:

   {{0.191, -0.021}, {0.24, 0.645}, {0.261, 1.36}, {0.283, 
     2.101}, {0.294, 2.742}, {0.31, 3.314}, {0.315, 3.952}, {0.336, 
     4.862}, {0.347, 5.635}, {0.358, 6.309}, {0.374, 7.015}, {0.39, 
     7.722}, {0.411, 8.462}, {0.416, 9.236}, {0.443, 10.01}, {0.454, 
     10.651}, {0.475, 11.256}, {0.502, 11.895}, {0.544, 12.434}, {0.598, 
     12.635}, {0.662, 12.298}, {0.71, 11.626}, {0.769, 10.784}, {0.817, 
     10.01}, {0.859, 9.303}, {0.902, 8.564}, {0.95, 7.824}, {0.998, 
     7.15}, {1.052, 6.442}, {1.105, 5.837}, {1.158, 5.199}, {1.233, 
     4.458}, {1.313, 3.817}, {1.399, 3.179}, {1.505, 2.64}, {1.596, 
     2.205}, {1.703, 1.799}, {1.81, 1.56}, {1.922, 1.261}, {2.055, 
     1.026}, {2.173, 0.857}, {2.301, 0.722}, {2.456, 0.553}, {2.605, 
     0.453}, {2.76, 0.385}}

Done.

Now you can fit it. To do this you need to have a function to which you are going to fit the data. Since you gave no function, I cannot help you further.

Have fun!

**Edit**: to address your second question. First of all the Planck if you use the Planck distribution, then the only fitting parameter may be the temperature. So you should not fix it to constant. Second, do not forget that your plot is not given in SI units, while the Planck formula you gave operates with them. So you need to adapt them. You might want to operate as follows:

```
  Clear[lst];
lst = {{0.191`, -0.021`}, {0.24`, 0.645`}, {0.261`, 1.36`}, {0.283`, 
     2.101`}, {0.294`, 2.742`}, {0.31`, 3.314`}, {0.315`, 
     3.952`}, {0.336`, 4.862`}, {0.347`, 5.635`}, {0.358`, 
     6.309`}, {0.374`, 7.015`}, {0.39`, 7.722`}, {0.411`, 
     8.462`}, {0.416`, 9.236`}, {0.443`, 10.01`}, {0.454`, 
     10.651`}, {0.475`, 11.256`}, {0.502`, 11.895`}, {0.544`, 
     12.434`}, {0.598`, 12.635`}, {0.662`, 12.298`}, {0.71`, 
     11.626`}, {0.769`, 10.784`}, {0.817`, 10.01`}, {0.859`, 
     9.303`}, {0.902`, 8.564`}, {0.95`, 7.824`}, {0.998`, 
     7.15`}, {1.052`, 6.442`}, {1.105`, 5.837`}, {1.158`, 
     5.199`}, {1.233`, 4.458`}, {1.313`, 3.817`}, {1.399`, 
     3.179`}, {1.505`, 2.64`}, {1.596`, 2.205`}, {1.703`, 
     1.799`}, {1.81`, 1.56`}, {1.922`, 1.261`}, {2.055`, 
     1.026`}, {2.173`, 0.857`}, {2.301`, 0.722`}, {2.456`, 
     0.553`}, {2.605`, 0.453`}, {2.76`, 0.385`}} /. {x_, 
     y_} -> {x*10^-6, y*10^12};
model = (2*h*c^2)/\[Lambda]^5*1/(Exp[(h*c)/(\[Lambda]*k*T)] - 1)
ff = FindFit[lst, model, {{T, 4000}}, \[Lambda]]
```

yielding

```
(*   {T -> 4974.56}   *)
```

Alternatively you may do this:

```
 Manipulate[
 Show[{

   Plot[(2*h*c^2)/\[Lambda]^5*1/(
     Exp[(h*c)/(\[Lambda]*k*T)] - 1), {\[Lambda], 0, 3*10^-6}],
   ListPlot[lst]

   }], {{T, 4990}, 4900, 5100}]
```

you should obtain this:

[image]

Once more, have fun!

Comment: The function's here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck's_law

Comment: @Chris Degnen I know, what is the function. Would you be so kind as to give it in Mma notations, and with numbers instead of Plank's constant and speed velocity. Just follow the rules of this site.

Comment: `h = 6.6260693*10^-34; c = 2.99792458*10^8; k = 
 1.3806505*10^-23; tmp = 5000;
planckfunction[tmp_, lambda_] := 
  2 h c^2/(((lambda*10^-6)^5) (Exp[h c/((lambda*10^-6) k tmp)] - 1));
Plot[planckfunction[tmp, lambda], {lambda, 0, 3}]`

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of information for me to go through. With regard to the actual curve, it's in fact not Planck's law which I merely used as a convenient example here, since I'm not at a liberty to disclose my original data.

Comment: @Chris Degnen Then I propose that you invent some data which look quite differently, but hold same important features, and the law which is not exactly the same as the necessary one but with the same parameters. Then it would be easier for you to use the help.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch there is some problem with the Memorize X and Memorize Y it says Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {} cannot be transposed. Part::partw: Part 2 of Transpose[{}] does not exist. and the "make the list of poits" dont gives nothing because of that, maybe

Comment: @Lucas Lopes Without your image and code, it is impossible to say what goes wrong. I guess that you did something wrong in application of the function. Try to make everything strict according to my description. It must work.

Comment: I have used the same picture of this post. Pasted the picture inside copyCurve[here].

Comment: @Lucas Lopes Since its creation many years ago and until the last time I used it (recently) it perfectly works for me. Many other people reported me that it works OK.