# Creating a plot from an image of the plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, import

I have an image of a plot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vug7H.jpg

```
Import["https://i.imgur.com/vNqm0Em.png"]
```

[image]

I want to create a plot of it, consistent with the scale in the picture, so I can find the area under the graph on certain intervals.

I followed the steps at [How to generate a Graph from a picture of a graph?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102262/how-to-generate-a-graph-from-a-picture-of-a-graph) but I get a completely black picture after I run the command

```
vertexI = SelectComponents[i, "Count", 10 < # < 100 &]
```

How can I get the plot I want and find the area under the graph?

Comment: related: [Recovering data points from an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1524/125)

Comment: Also related: [How to make a curve selectable from a scanned image and convert it to a list of coordinates](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44355/731) and [Extracting data from analog screen photograph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162080/731)

Comment: Comapre [Wiki:Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph) and [Wiki:Plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot), and consider which noun is less confusing in computerscience & math related context.

Comment: How robust does this need to be? Is it just for this picture or does it have to work on other similar pictures as well?