# How to get the coordinates of the x-intercept from a plot?

Tags: plotting

Assuming that I only have access to the plot and not to the function that was used to generate it, how can I get the coordinates of the x-intercept of this plot?

[image]

Comment: Please make precise a few points. First, what do you mean by "having access to the plot". Do you have the plot in the form of an image? Say, a pdf file with the image? Or something else? Second, please make it more precise, what do you mean under "x-intercept"? Do you mean the value of x close to 6.3, where the plot ends up, or something else?

Comment: I have the plot as an image only. The x-intercepts are all those points where their y-coordinate is equal to 0. I would like to get their x-coordinates.

Comment: In this case, there is a way, if you agree that the points of the plot you will obtain with a certain approximation. Some time ago I published a function entitled "copyCurve" that can help you. You find it here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358