# How to get sliders in a row in manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, alignment

```
Manipulate[v + t, {v, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1},
           ControlPlacement -> Left, ControlType -> VerticalSlider]
```

puts the second slider below the first one. How to get it on the left of the first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can wrap each control with `Control` and use them with `Row`:

```
Manipulate[v + t, Row[{Control@{v, 0, 1}, Control@{t, 0, 1}}], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, ControlType -> VerticalSlider]
```

[image]

2. Alternatively, you can use the `Method` option to modify the setting
   for the suboption `"ControlAreaDisplayFunction"` to organize the
   control area content as you like:

```
Manipulate[v + t, {v, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider, 
 Method -> "ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> 
   (Row[Column[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ #[[1]], Spacer[10]] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358) answer I introduced a function copyCurve which returned a manipulator containing a number of sliders and other interactive elements organized in rows and columns like in the image below:

[image]

Just have a look. Have fun!