# List of Coordinates at Mouse Position

Tags: front-end

I have the following image

[image]

I want to semi-automate the process of me collecting coordinates for all the vertices. What I have in mind is putting my cursor over each node and appending the coordinate to a list

```
x={};
ClickPane[img, AppendTo[x,#]&]
```

This is somewhat not ideal because it's not at all responsive. It would be nice if it would draw a small circle over the image point every time and maybe keep the most recent one a different color. Also an action that ends the `ClickPane` would be ideal.

I have little experience with front end fucntions in mathematica so any help would be great.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html)?

Comment: Yup this is exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the function copyCurve here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358