# Two different variables in a Do Loop

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-request, procedural-programming, iterators

I am trying to use the code developed by @Alex Trounev here: [Numerical solution of an iterative equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235259/numerical-solution-of-an-iterative-equation) for different kind of `q`. I am not sure how to incorporate  two different parameters in a `Do` loop to achieve this.

Here's my manual try to plot `Tf` and `cp` for different `q`:

These are the parameters in common for any `q`:

```
ah = 342496; (*J/mol*)
R = 8.314; (*J/mol.K*)
A = 7.6*10^-38; (*s*)
b = 0.67;
x = 0.49;
T0 = 500;(*K*)
Tfinal = 350;(*K*)
Tf[0] = T0;(*Initial condition for Tf*)
```

Here's to implement a `q=-0.1/60` (q1) and plot it:

```
(*q1*)
q = -0.1/60;
dt = Abs[(T0 - Tfinal)/(300*q)];(*s. This ensures n to be 300*)
n = IntegerPart[Abs[(T0 - Tfinal)/dt/q]]; (*number of steps*)
dT = dt*q; (*K*)
T[k_] := T0 + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(k\)]dT\);

Do[
 tau[k] = A*Exp[(x ah)/(R T[k]) + (1 - x) ah/(R Tf[k - 1])];
 
 Tf[k] = T0 + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
      1\), \(k\)]\(dT*\((1 - Exp[\((\(-\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
             i\), \(k\)]\((\((dT)\)/\((q*tau[j])\))\)^b\)\))\)])\)\)\);
 
 , {k, n} (*Do[exp,{i,imax}]. k starts at 1.*)]

(*Visualization for q1*)

Tfc = Table[{T[k], Tf[k]}, {k, 
   n}]; (*Creates a table of Tk and Tfk such \
{{Tk1,Tfk1},{Tk2,Tfk2}...} from k to n*)
T[0] = T0;
cp = Table[{T[k], (Tf[k] - Tf[k - 1])/(T[k] - T[k - 1])}, {k, n}];

ListPlot[Tfc, PlotRange -> {{350, 500}, {400, 500}}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AxesLabel -> {"T", "Tf"}]
ListPlot[cp, PlotRange -> {{350, 500}, {-0.5, 3}}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AxesLabel -> {"T", "cp"}]
```

Here's to implement a `q=-1/60` (q2) and plot it (the same except for changing `q`):

```
(*q2*)
q = -1/60;
dt = Abs[(T0 - Tfinal)/(300*q)];(*s. This ensures n to be 300*)
n = IntegerPart[Abs[(T0 - Tfinal)/dt/q]]; (*number of steps*)
dT = dt*q; (*K*)
T[k_] := T0 + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(k\)]dT\);

Do[
 tau[k] = A*Exp[(x ah)/(R T[k]) + (1 - x) ah/(R Tf[k - 1])];
 
 Tf[k] = T0 + \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 
      1\), \(k\)]\(dT*\((1 - Exp[\((\(-\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 
             i\), \(k\)]\((\((dT)\)/\((q*tau[j])\))\)^b\)\))\)])\)\)\);
 
 , {k, n} (*Do[exp,{i,imax}]. k starts at 1.*)]


(*Visualization for q2*)

Tfc = Table[{T[k], Tf[k]}, {k, 
   n}]; (*Creates a table of Tk and Tfk such \
{{Tk1,Tfk1},{Tk2,Tfk2}...} from k to n*)
T[0] = T0;
cp = Table[{T[k], (Tf[k] - Tf[k - 1])/(T[k] - T[k - 1])}, {k, n}];

ListPlot[Tfc, PlotRange -> {{350, 500}, {400, 500}}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AxesLabel -> {"T", "Tf"}]
ListPlot[cp, PlotRange -> {{350, 500}, {-0.5, 3}}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, AxesLabel -> {"T", "cp"}]
```

**Question:**

What I want is to be able to do each plot for different `q`'s in a single plot in a automatic manner without having to repeat the code at each q. The `q` values I want to plot are `q1=-0.1/60`,`q2=-1/60`,`q1=-10/60`, `q1=-80/60`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap everything in a `Module` (added bonus: localize variables and definitions)
2. Use it to define a function that takes `q` as a parameter
3. Build a `Table` that calls your `function` with the appropriate values of `q`
4. Done!

```
ClearAll[function]
function[q_, T0_: 500, Tfinal_: 350, ah_: 342496] :=
 Module[{R, A, b, x, dt, n, dT, T, Tf, tau, Tfc, cp},
  R = 8.314;(*J/mol.K*)
  A = 7.6*10^-38;(*s*)
  b = 0.67;
  x = 0.49;
  Tf[0] = T0;(*Initial condition for Tf*)
  
  dt = Abs[(T0 - Tfinal)/(300*q)];
  n = IntegerPart[Abs[(T0 - Tfinal)/dt/q]];
  dT = dt*q;
  T[k_] := T0 + Sum[dT, {i, 1, k}];
  
  Do[
   tau[k] = A Exp[(x ah)/(R T[k]) + (1 - x) (ah/(R Tf[k - 1]))];   
   Tf[k] = T0 + Sum[dT (1 - Exp[-Sum[(dT/(q*tau[j]))^b, {j, i, k}]]), {i, 1, k}],
   {k, n}
  ];
  
  Tfc = Table[{T[k], Tf[k]}, {k, n}]; T[0] = T0; 
  cp = Table[{T[k], (Tf[k] - Tf[k - 1])/(T[k] - T[k - 1])}, {k, n}];
  {Tfc, cp}
 ]
```

Then you can call function with whatever value of `q`; I also added the possibility of changing initial and final temperatures, and `ah`. However, if left off, the function will assume 500K and 350K respectively, as you had in your code:

```
data = Table[
         {q, function[q]},
         {q, {-0.1/60, -1/60, -10/60, -80/60.}}
       ];

ListPlot[
  data[[All, 2, 1]],
  PlotRange -> {{350, 500}, {400, 500}},
  ImageSize -> Medium, AxesLabel -> {"T", "Tf"}
]

ListPlot[
  data[[All, 2, 2]],
  PlotRange -> {{350, 500}, {-0.5, 3}},
  ImageSize -> Medium, AxesLabel -> {"T", "cp"}
]
```

[image: plot of all Tf traces]

[image: plot of all cp traces]

Comment: MarcoB the code is absolutely fantastic!! Thank you so much!. If I can ask one more question: How can I plot all the `q`'s in the same plot (as to have 4 different graphs in the same plot)?. I am accepting your answer already and again I appreciate it very much, !

Comment: @John Sure, easiest will be to have the function return the values rather than the plots. See edit.

Comment: MarcoB thank you so much!. I will have both versions of the code to consider. Again, thank you for your kind help !

Comment: @ MarcoB may I ask you another easy question for you. If I want to get the value of Tf[n] from the module to use it as the input for a second module. In this case, on heating I want to do exactly the same module that you constructed but instead of T0 being 350, I want T0 to be Tf[n] from the first module. How can I do this?

Comment: @ MarcoB thank you!. The problem is that in this case I don't know what the value of Tf[n] is. In other words, I guess what I am asking if for a way to get outside (as a global variable) the value that I will get for Tf[n] inside the module. i don't know the value of Tf[n] before executing the first module.

Comment: @John Hmm maybe I'm not following. For each run, wouldn't `Tf[n]` be the last value of `Tf`? In other words, the function returns `Tfc`, which is a list of pairs of `T[k]` and `Tf[k]`. The last value of the last pair is `Tf[n]`, right? So wouldn't `function[yourQ][[1, -1, -1]]` be `Tf[n]` for that run?

Comment: MarcoB, Once again you are correct! I didn't see it that way. Thank you so much !