# Distance between two points in a picture

Tags: image-processing, distance

I have this picture:

[image]

I'de like to obtain the distance between two of these points. The black scale bar is 3$\mu m$.

To do so, I import the image to Mathematica and call it pic. Then by finding dominant colors, I define red as

```
red = RGBColor[0.827134595933227, 0.00309700865836607, 
      0.08256587730260687, 1.];
```

And then I obtain the coordinates of the centers of the dots as

```
  centroid[pic_,color_] := ComponentMeasurements[
  Binarize@ColorDetect[pic,color],
  "Centroid"
  ][[All,2]]

  coordinates = centroid[pic,red]
```

So

```
            {{5.5, 39.5}, {13.9828, 37.5345}, {34.2308, 37.8846}, {23.6034, 
            34.8103}, {5.38571, 32.5571}, {15., 29.}, {1.19231, 24.8077}}
```

Now, let's say we want to obtain the distance between two points of coordinates: {15., 29.} and {23.6034, 34.8103} which is 10.3816.

Now, my question is that how can I also determine the size of scale and obtain the real distance between these two points?

Comment: You can try using the function copyCurve [here][1]. It was aimed for other purposes, but it can also easily do what you need. 


  [1]: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c/44358#44358

Comment: This can be done with the copyCurve function. As well as the distance definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's get the scale bar out of the image. There are a few ways to do this (`MorphologicalBinarize` and friends), but I went with the more eye-bally approach of using `ColorReplace`. Here, we're replacing black pixels with white, and all other pixels with black, to get a mask. Note that ColorReplace has a third argument `d`, which you could use to fine-tune what it sees as "black".

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR6UY.gif"]

c = ColorReplace[i, {Black -> White, _ -> Black}]
```

[image]

Compare with a simple `MorphologicalBinarize` - the choice is yours:

[image]

Now we can get the bounding box of our rectangle, and simply take the difference:

```
box = ComponentMeasurements[c, "BoundingBox"][[1, 2]]

Differences /@ Transpose@box
```

> `{{38.}, {5.}}`

So the longest dimension of our bounding box is 38 pixels long, and the short side is 5 pixels long.

Just to check, I counted the pixels another way, using `SequenceCases` on our replaced image, and each line of `1`s, the pixels of the scale bar, had a length of 38.

```
SequenceCases[
 Flatten@MorphologicalComponents[c], {p : Repeated[1]} :> Length@{p}]
```

> `{38, 38, 38, 38, 38}`

Either way, we get about 38 pixels, so now we know the length of the bar, and thus we can get the size of a pixel (assuming pixels are square here).

```
pixelLength = Quantity[3, "Microns"] / 38
```

> `Quantity[0.0789474, "Microns"]`

and now if we get the Euclidean distance between your points and multiply it by our pixel length, we get the distance in microns.

```
EuclideanDistance[{5.5, 39.5}, {13.9828, 37.5345}] * pixelLength
```

> `Quantity[0.687437, "Microns"]`

This answer will not hold up well if the bar is not always aligned perfectly to the image border, as it is in your test image. You could consider `ComponentMeasurements[c, "Length"]` or `"CaliperLength"` to get the length of the bar instead in that case. However, it may take the distances between opposite corners of the bar, which may not be what you want.

Comment: I did not have my coffee before this answer - I would wait until a better-caffeinated person comes by and gives a better response. I suspect my approach is not scientific enough and potentially just plain wrong.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you could simply create a function called `pixelDistanceInMicrons[p1_, p2_, pixelLength_] := EuclideanDistance[p1, p2] * pixelLength` and call it like `pixelDistanceInMicrons[{5.5, 39.5}, {13.9828, 37.5345}, Quantity[0.0789474, "Microns"]]`.

Comment: You could also count the pixels by hand, I suppose.

Comment: If the bar is diagonal, counting pixels in the way I have done it here will not work, as I am counting them left to right. As I mention, I think `"CaliperLength"` will do a reasonable job in this case. I am hopeful someone else will post a more scientific answer as I'm not convinced this method would be enough for Real Science and I'm not sure I can help you further because of that. Hope my answer at least helps you find your way to a more useful result :)